# Fire event in gwt java testing not changing the value of checkbox

Tags: java, unit-testing, gwt, radio-button

I added three radio buttons in a group and it works fine when I load page from browser.

Java code:

```
@UiHandler({
"RadioButton1",
"RadioButton2",
"RadioButton3"
})  
void radioButtonClickHandler(ClickEvent event){
  if(RadioButton1.getValue()){
    // do something
  } else if(RadioButton2.getValue()) {
    // do something
  } else if (RadioButton3.getValue()){
    // do something
  }
}
```

I am trying to write test cases for this function.

```
public void TestRadio1ClickEvent(){
    // all values set 
    // Value of Radiobutton2 set to true
    view.RadioButton1.fireEvent(new ClickEvent() {});

    assertTrue(view.RadioButton1.getValue());
    assertFalse(view.RadioButton2.getValue());
    assertFalse(view.RadioButton3.getValue());
}
```

The values of radio buttons are not changing when I fire click event. Value of RadioButton1 remains false and RadioButton2 remains true.

I can set values manually in click handler but I don't want to do that. How is clicking of button different from firing event? Does click change radio button value and then call click handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following method on the radio button. 
setValue(java.lang.Boolean value, boolean fireEvents)

```
    radioButton.setValue(true,true)
```